# Prevent JS-Window from closing without showing a prompt

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-4

In my MS CRM 4.0-application, there are several things to do before the window is closed.
So I have to stop the window from closing in the onbeforeunload-function and do my stuff in different locations.
This works already, but only if I show the dialog by returning some message in my onbeforeunload-function and the user chooses "stay on page" (or something like this)

Is it possible to skip this dialog and stop the window from closing?

I know there are several reasons, why this shouldn't work, but, e.g. in my CRM-application it is neccessary.

Comment: No, it's not possible, and thank goodness for that. :-)

Comment: @Pointy I +1'd your comment on principle (developers, please don't hijack my browser!), but there **is** a frustrating lack of modality in web-based software that would come in handy in certain application use-cases. One can create simulated modal dialogs in javascript, but a page refresh breaks out of them with a hammer.

Comment: What are some of the things you aim to achieve before a user closes a window? For things such as saving/caching, your best bet is to do things like that periodically, or after a user does something (other than close a window).

Comment: A client has to be informed. He does some things, like closing other windows and so on. But it doesn't work if I close the window before

Comment: Surely they get the option? IE: Save changes/close windows or not, up to you. If there are mandatory tasks that they should have done, you can always catch it in the back end, right? No need to beat them with their own browser...

Comment: Don't open popups, half of the problems will be gone.